# LU разложение OpenMP

Tags: openmp, c, алгоритм, c++, распараллеливание

Почему параллельная версия работает за то же время или больше чем последовательная версия алгоритма? Что я сделал не так?

LU разложение с помощью OpenMP:

```
void lup_od_omp(double* a, int n){

int i,j,k;

for(k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(a,n,k) private(i,j)
    for(i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i*n + k] /= a[k*n + k];
        for(j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[i*n + j] -= a[i*n + k]*a[k*n + j];
        }
    }
}
}
```

P.S. Матрица хранится в одномерном массиве. Та же самая ситуация с временем выполнения (параллельно >= последовательно) и с матрицей, хранящейся в двумерном массиве.

Comment: У Вас сколько ядер (CPU Cores) в узле и какова размерность матрицы?

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo (2 ядра без HT),тестировалось на матрице 2000 на 2000, время последовательно = параллельно = 8с. Компилировалось в VS 2010. Правда при Debug режиме параллельная версия все же быстрее последовательной. Так же я потестил другим компилятором, MinGW, при отключенных флагах оптимизации -O или -O2 параллельный быстрее, при включение одного из этих флагов параллельный = последовательному. К сожалению, протестировать под другой ОС не удалось. Возможно, проблема кроется в нитях Windows.

Comment: Вероятно, вам будет полезна [эта статья][1].

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/134547/

Comment: C VS2010, допустим, понятно. Но почему в MinGW та же самая ситуация?

Comment: А тут не может быть конфликтов по данным из-за того что потоки лезут в смежные ячейки? Например, a[k*n + j]

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос старый, но без ответа.

Как вариант - проблема в том, что массив `a` совместно используется для **записи** в потоках. В таком случае параллельный вариант вполне может работать даже медленнее последовательного. На большем количестве ядер, думаю, эффект должен быть очевиднее.

Каждая запись на ядре `0` будет вытеснять любое чтение на ядре `1` и наоборот - запись на ядре `1` будет вытеснять чтение по этим же адресам на ядре `0` (см. "когерентность кэша").

Решить проблему можно, если выделить каждому потоку свой буфер для сохранения результатов (равноудаленный друг от друга как минимум на 32/64 байта, а еще лучше - выровненный при этом на те же 32/64 байта [кэш-линия]).

Замечание от @Михаил М, думаю, тоже в силе, но в таком случае, я уже сомневаюсь насчет корректности параллельного алгоритма: очевидно, в смежной ячейке может находиться значение, модифицированное другим потоком, а это поменяет результат вычислений.